# Why is there a discrepancy in the E192 series?

Tags: resistors, standard, accuracy

For all series from E48 through E192, this holds true:

$$
value = 10^{\frac i n}
$$

where *i* is the zero-based index in the series and *n* is the length of the series. The one exception is E192[185]:

$$
listed = 9.20
$$

$$
expected = \text{round}\left( 10^{\frac {185} {192}} ,2\right) 
= \text{round}\left( 9.19479... ,2\right) 
\approx 9.19
$$

It seems that industrially, 9.20 is indeed much more common, but to muddy the waters even further, Vishay offers both of these parts:

- `RN55E9191BRE6`
- `RN55E9201BRE6`

What is going on here?

There is a [random post](https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?373015-E192-series-formula-(and-formula-for-other-series-as-well)) on EDAboard that talks about the same issue.

This is related to, but not the same as, [A question about E12 series resistors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236255/a-question-about-e12-series-resistors) - it's well-known that E24 and below differ from the exact logarithmic formula for historical reasons, but no such historical reasons are listed in (for instance) the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers) for the higher series.

Comment: possible dupe https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236255/a-question-about-e12-series-resistors  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renard_series

Comment: Certainly related to, but I believe distinct from. I have edited the question.

Comment: That said, the answers basically cover my question anyway. So yes, I will close this.