# Why are capacitor voltage ratings such strange values?

Tags: capacitor

This is a similar type of question to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67975/what-is-the-reason-that-the-value-47-is-so-popular-in-electrical-engineering) about the use of the number 47.

I was looking at ordering some parts just like any other day and until now I've never really thought about it much, but I realised that the voltage ratings for capacitors seem really strange (to me at least).

The standard voltage ratings seem to be:

- 6.3 V
- 10 V
- 16 V
- 25 V
- 35 V
- 50 V
- 63 V
- 100 V
- 160 V

I've taken these values and plotted them on a graph to see if there was any correlation and it seems like there is an exponential correlation.

[image]

[image]

My actual questions are:.

1. *How were these values initially decided upon?*
2. *Was/Is the voltage rating dictated by the material used and has just stuck over the years?*
3. *Are there any other components out there that use the same voltage ratings?*

Comment: Well, one thing pops right out to me because I used to use vacuum tubes. The 6.3V was one of the common filament voltages, though that was an AC rms figure. Lots of transformers included a secondary for that.

Comment: @jonk Not only it was AC, but you're also not supposed to pick a cap rated at the exact voltage you have.

Comment: @dmitry: Of course. The whole thing is only about the number itself reminding me. Not about suggesting anything like you seem to imagine I did. I was addressing #3 of the OP's question. I took that to mean ANY.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's mainly all about preferred numbers: -

[image]

See [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_number) wiki page and, see also [**this**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246699/why-are-there-3-15a-fuses/246722#246722) stack exchange answer about fuses values.

It's all about splitting the difference between 1 and 10. For instance \$\sqrt{10}\$ is ratiometrically half way between 1 and 10 and the cube root splits into the numbers 2.154 and 4.642. Multiply by 2.154 again and you get 10.

So, if you split the range 1 to 10 into 5 chunks you get 1, 1.5849, 2.5119, 3.9811, 6.3096 and finally 10.

These values approximate to 1, 1.6, 2.5, 4.0, 6.3 and 10.

Like I said earlier, this is mainly the reason but I suspect the prevelence of 24 V systems may have caused the 35V capacitor to come about and, of course the 40 V capacitor is not that uncommon: -

[image]

Comment: @agentL and that is precisely what i have delivered. Try again if u have a valid point that somehow I have missed.

Comment: ops, you're right and I was wrong. However, your answer consists of nothing but a cryptic table and 2 links. Maybe if you could add more explanation it would not look like a table of resistor values. That's what I mistook it for.

Comment: It woudl be nice if you would expand on it more.  I certainly didn't understand anything about the answer until I followed the link, and even then 35V doesn't fit into the table.  StackExchange prefers answers where the content is in the answer itself, not the links.  That way they're not as affected when the links expire.

Comment: @Meower68 see edit

Comment: @CortAmmon see edit

Comment: @Agent_L see edit

Comment: By the way, a nice feature of these series is that they give round numbers for doublings (octaves, in frequency domain, from audio) as well as decades. A pure geometric subdivision of a decade uses the factor \$10^(1/10)\$. This yields the values 1.2589..., 1.5848..., 1.9952..., 2.5118..., 3.1622..., 3.9810..., 5.0118..., 6.3095..., 7.9432, 10.  By numerical dumb luck, some of the values are close to 2.0, 4.0 and 8.0! So R10 nicely approximates three-steps-per-doubling (or octave, in frequencies) as well as ten-steps-per-decade.

Comment: @Kaz when talking about decibels of loss / gain, Hams frequently use 2x as 3 dB gain (it is, as you point out, 1.9952 but pretty close to 2).  So 3 db gain = 2x, 6 db gain = 4x, 9 db gain = 8x.  Common exercise is "if 10db gain = 10x and 9 db gain = 8x, what's 1 db gain?" Roughtly 5/4x (1.2589, as you point out).  These approximations are widely used in the Amateur Radio community.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of components' values lie equally spaced on a logarithmic scale (i.e. are exponential, as you have observed). This makes a great deal of sense, because component values span multiple orders of magnitude. In my parts box, I have capacitors from 10pF to 2.6mF (over 8 orders of magnitude) and resistors from 1ohm to 1Gohm (9 orders of magnitude). You wouldn't want to linearly space component values. If you did resistors in increments of 1ohm, you would have poor resolution at the low end, but your product catalog would need to have a billion items in it! The values could be linearly spaced within a decade, i.e. do 0.01ohm increments for resistors between 1 and 10ohms, 10ohm increments for resistors between 1 and 10kohms, for example, but what makes the decade cutoffs significant? It's better to have the resolution of selectable values to be proportional to the value itself everywhere, rather than chunked into select ranges.

Comment: OP asked about voltages, not values.

Comment: Oops, true, but the same principal still applies.

Comment: @agent_l the exact same reasons apply for the value of the voltage as they do for the value of the capacitance (or resistance, or whatever)

Comment: @mbrig Yes, I get it. But if it was that obvious, OP wouldn't have to ask, wouldn't he? Plus, with voltages it's bit different, because you're not looking for rating exactly as operating voltage, but for anything over your voltage (+ safety margin). Overspeccing here is possible while with value is not. Unlike values, there are typical voltage that majority of circuits run at. And the materials that capacitors are made of have different characteristics when handling voltage or overvoltage. There is much more to OP's voltage ratings question than to a value question.

Comment: Often you don't get the exact value you want either, though. I've heard of putting a 1% low value resistor in parallel with a 5% high value resistor, or a 5% low value in series with a 1% high value, to achieve a resistor value that's not in the product catalog at a reasonable price (especially in the old days, I know some former HP engineers, product catalogs seem to be bigger today). But often the value isn't critical, just as voltage isn't critical. I don't think the cases are all that different really.

Comment: @Agent_L No there isn't. The question is about capacitor voltage ratings, and the answer is about the preferred value series. None of the extraneous factors you mention has anything to do with it.

Comment: @EJP Please read the question again. It has 3 bullet points at the end and only first one has been answered by anyone so far.

Comment: Well, to points 2 and 3 I say, yes to point 2, materials have some bearing on voltage ratings but you can always change the thickness of the dielectric, so you can achieve whatever rating you want within reason, and no I don't think so to point 3, because other passive linear components are spec'd on current or power dissipation, capacitors being the exception due to their limited dielectric strength, and semiconductor product lines tend not to have complete ratings/specs matrixes like the passive linear parts, for those you get to choose one parameter and then just overspec the others.