# Why does `buck` mean `step-down`?

Tags: terminology, history

I just read about buck converters and boost converters and buck/boost converters.  Great stuff.

But, why is a step-down converter called a buck converter?

I tried to research this myself.  According to Google Book search, the phrase `buck-boost transformer` was in use at least as early at 1891 in a periodical called Architectural Review.

Comment: I suspect the term as applied in electric systems may have been created originally for transformers -- more specifically for autotransformers -- and relates to an idea that was commonly known back in the day. Logs were bucked (either under- or over- bucked) depending on from which end of the log sections were cut for milling. (Starting at the thicker base and working up or starting at the top and working down.)  A bucking transformer can be seen as doing just that. And I suspect that's where the first author of the term got the idea since logging was a commonly shared experience in the 1800s.

Comment: I don't think it's opinion-based. Personally I don't like etymology questions, but if we don't want them anymore, we should rather have a meta discussion than closing a single question for the wrong reason.

Comment: BTW, I replaced "etymology" with "terminology" which has a much wider use on this site.

Comment: Awesome answer in comment above by jonk about wood logs is etymology. Answers below especially one by marcelm, are terminology. IMHO removing etymology tag is wrong *if OP asked about the origins/history of expression* (which is not clarified). Definitely not opinion based, and great question.

Comment: I am specifically interested in the etymology.

Comment: Every buck converter lowers voltage AND raises current, right?  (Ok, this is terminology.)  Is the same true for every buck transformer?

Comment: I agree that @jonk's comment should be an answer. Based on that comment, I've decided to ask the radio show `A Way With Words` to settle this.

Comment: @daveloyall I think your question is very interesting. I [answered a question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/381906/38098) about how we wound up with the values seen in the E-series for resistors. That study took me in a very fun and interesting direction. I hope they choose to research and discuss your question to them. Let us know, somehow? (I didn't provide an answer because I really don't have a clue. I did learn some uses of "buck", recalling buckboards plus using a heavy hammer behind something pounded from the other side to add inertia -- both of which I've experienced.)

Comment: As promised, I've accepted the answer that matched [what the radio show said](https://twitter.com/wayword/status/1167566740261412865).  (Though, their response was not particularly satisfying!)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the same sense as to "buck" a trend:

1. to oppose or resist (something that seems oppressive or inevitable).
   "the shares bucked the market trend"
   synonyms:   resist, oppose, contradict, defy, fight (against), go against, kick against
   "it takes guts to buck the system"

So you're "bucking" the input voltage to reduce the output voltage.

Comment: Which is more applicable to transformers than to regulators, but the idea of "bucking" as "reducing voltage" probably came from transformer usage, and got transferred to regulator usage.

Comment: Buck regulators use an inductor which opposes the current flow when the switch opens. So it's just as valid as the transformer use.

Comment: @gbarry Right, we don't call linear regulators "buck" regulators

Comment: There is a deeper root. It comes from the action of the buck converter being similar to a bull's or horse's bucking, which throws the rider down.

Answer (score 5):

I may be wrong(apparently there is no way to qualify any answer here as correct), but I had always assumed that "buck" referred to an action similar to a "bucking bronco or bull".  A buck converter sends a voltage pulse only as often as it needs to in order to provide the rectified and filtered DC output required, just as a "bucking bronco or bull" will "buck" as often as he feels he needs to in order to eject the rider or loosen the strap.

Comment: Please, no downvotes because you dislike rodeos. Even though I understand where you may be coming from, it is a very plausible answer...

Comment: (No one is downvoting?) I honestly thought it  had to do with animals as well when I first heard the term but I knew that it probably wasn't correct. The verb "buck" could mean to be resistant against something. I think there could be a way to qualify an answer and that's looking it up in the dictionary :)

Comment: @KingDuken - I know, but right after I posted the answer I had visions of SJW bombardment, so I was just trying to preempt that :).  If the term isn't derived from my suggested possible answer, than it does likely refer to resistance, as you say...

Comment: Since most of the switching topologies work by making controlled pulses in response to operating conditions, it's hard to imagine that we'd take the "bucking" notion and specifically put it on the one that's a step-down.

Comment: @gbarry - I sort of see it in the opposite scenario.  An animal "bucks" as high and often as it need to in order to obtain it's goal, I see it as "providing action only to the extent that is required", rather than the dictionary version, which implies more of a "resistance" or "opposition" aspect, and would seem more analogous to the implementation in a linear regulator...

Comment: @Hitek Not entirely sure why you would think that would invite "SJW bombardment"...

Comment: @probably_someone Because there are people out there who will take any technical (or other) non-controversial item and decide to turn it into a political/ideological war. It is stupid/crazy - on all sides. But it most definitely happens. I have seen it in comments on articles about Tesla (articles that are purely technical in nature) and many other places.

Comment: @manassehkatz Who are you to decide what is "non-controversial"? Why is your definition of the term better than someone else's definition? In any case, pre-emptively assuming and making a point of saying that you expect this to happen to your comment either a) makes it look like you're looking for a way to be the victim, or b) makes it look like you're purposely trying to get a rise out of people. Neither is a particularly good look.

Comment: @probably_someone Everyone has their own definition of "controversial". My point is that I see (as Hitek was concerned) far too often where a *technical* or similar posting/article/etc. that is clearly not intended to make a political statement gets "hijacked" in responses to become a political item. The specific example here is, I believe, typical - concern about some people taking references to rodeos (quite arguably abusive treatment of animals - I'm not disputing the problem and neither is Hitek) and turning it from merely "source of a term" and having the purely technical answer become...

Comment: a target for anyone who dislikes (for any reason) rodeos. In other words, Hitek's mention of *rodeo* should not become a license for people to downvote and/or complain about Hitek. But that type of behavior has become all too common on many sites. Thankfully not so much on StackExchange, as moderators (and long-time members) generally do a good job of keeping things on track.

Comment: @manassehkatz Three questions: 1) Why does an article being technical prevent it from being controversial? For example, at least in the US, virtually any research paper published in the field of climate change is controversial. 2) How do you know the intent of the author? In particular, how do you know the intent better than the people who are objecting? 3) Why is the lack of intent a complete exoneration of the author? I could see it as a mitigating factor, at best. Ultimately, aren't people supposed to be at least somewhat responsible for the consequences of what they say?

Comment: "climate change" is a perfect example. I **expect** an article on climate change (whether supporting or denying it) to elicit comments (supporting or opposing the claims of the paper *or even semi-related issues like **consequences** of climate change when the article is more about causes, etc.*. That is **normal**. What is not normal, IMHO, is, for example, someone to take an article about technical aspects of Tesla (just to use a very high-profile example) - e.g., latest features like Summons or Sentry Mode or whatever *that have nothing inherently to do with climate change* and then...

Comment: simply because "Tesla as a company relates to controversial topics" get into a discussion of climate change (which Tesla/Elon Musk certainly have a lot to do with). In other words, put the "discussion of controversial items" where it belongs. To use the immediate example here, if Hitek said "go to a rodeo and see what they do, ain't it awesome, that's what 'buck' converters do" would be an invitation to downvotes/comments/criticism/etc. But a simple statement of "I think this is where the word 'buck' comes from" **should not, IMHO, be controversial**. End of my part - I'll stick to technical.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98048/discussion-between-probably-someone-and-manassehkatz).

Answer (score 2):

Question probably belongs on [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com). It arises from bucking being an action an animal takes to throw riders off or down, so a buck converter "throws" the voltage down by a repetitive "bucking" mechanism.

> ## buck (v.1)
>
> of a horse, "make a violent back-arched leap in an effort to throw off a rider," 1848, apparently "jump like a buck," from buck (n.1). Related: Bucked; bucking. Buck up "cheer up" is from 1844, probably from the noun in the "man" sense.

(from etymonline.com)

Answer (score 1):

*Step-down converters* is really a subclass of DC-DC converters, while a *buck converter* is one specific topology ("brand") of step-down converter. In essence, a buck converter is a step-down converter, but not every step-down converter is a buck converter. In theory, anyway.

Let's look at an overview of the various non-isolated DC-DC converter topologies:

## Step-down

- [Buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter)

## Step-up/down

- [Inverting buck-boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck%E2%80%93boost_converter)
- [SEPIC converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter)
- [Ćuk converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%86uk_converter)
- [Zeta converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply#Non-isolated_topologies)

## Step-up

- [Boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter)

As you can see, the subclasses are *step-up*, *step-down*, and *step-up/down*, and there are some topologies in each subclass. You can also see that there's only one topology in the step-down subclass: the buck converter. So:

> But, why is a step-down converter called a buck converter?

Because buck converters are step-down converters, *and* in practice all step-down converters are buck converters. The names refer to different things, but in practice it doesn't matter, so they're used interchangeably.

The Texas Instruments book [Power Topologies Handbook](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ug/slyu036/slyu036.pdf) (by Markus Zehendner and Matthias Ulmann) also has a good overview of the various topologies (also including isolating converters).

If you want to know where the name *"buck converter"* comes from; I don't know, but the other answers try to address that.

Answer (score 0):

The buck converter is so named because the inductor always “bucks” or acts against the input voltage.