# 31-5 kA rating of switchgear

Tags: short-circuit, maximum-ratings

25 kA, 31,5 kA and 40 kA are typical ratings of switchgear with respect to maximum short-circuit current capabilities (typically denoted \$I''_k\$)

I can understand 40 and 25 as they are nice numbers - but 31.5 is downright ugly.
How has that number become an standard ?
Does anyone know the history or background here?

Comment: It's about sqrt(1000) rounded reasonably nicely.

Comment: It is also -11 ln(2) + 15 π - 4 sqrt(3) - 5 sqrt(2) + 6. Rounded much more nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of a power series.  To a close approximation, 25 x 1,25 = 31,5.  Then 31,5 x 1,25 = 40.  The next few values are 50 and 63, which also appear a lot in component specifications.

Comment: I'll accept that. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [why-is-the-number-63-popular-in-electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/564511/why-is-the-number-63-popular-in-electronics/564523#564523). It's part of the R10 geometric series with ten steps per decade.